# Python3-glob and Python3-shutil Missing in Bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Using `openembedded-core` Morty branch:

For whatever reason, python 2 has these package but when attempting to run:

`bitbake python3-glob`

and

`bitbake python3-shutil`

These packages are not available. When installing just `python3` as part of a project they are missing as well.

However, another "standard package" (not sure if this is an accurate statement but this comes included in python3 on debian) `subprocess` can be installed by adding `python3-subprocess` as a dependency.

Is `glob` and `shutil` part of some larger `python3` standard packages recipe?

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

the `openembedded-core` Python3 recipe comes with a file called [python-3.5-manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/morty/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-3.5-manifest.inc). This file outlines different sub-recipes of python3.

`glob` and `shutil` are available by building `python3-shell`.

It appears for these to show up in an image they must be added to `IMAGE_INSTALL` in your image recipe.